# How to arrange VARCHAR column?

Tags: php, mysql

I have table which contain varchar column .This table will be used for pagination.
please see SQL Fiddle for the table structure.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db5467/53

It contain column `g_season` now when i fired query

```
SELECT * FROM(SELECT * FROM Games WHERE g_season > 'cvxv' ORDER BY g_season ASC ) s LIMIT 1
```

it gives me correct `g_id=7` but when i put 'dasd' it gives me `g_id=10` but it should be `g_id=12` this is because 7 and 12 `g_id` column contain g_Season and 'dasd' and sql will fetch last matching row and it is nothing but the `g_id=10`

Comment: can you give any more details? what do you mean by because 7 and 12 g_id column contain g_Season and 'dasd' ?

Comment: why are you using `>` more than in the query? its hard to understand what outcome you want with your question

Comment: What you want exactly?

Comment: when u go to sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db5467/62  u will find that my current query is giving g_id=7 result which is correct and now when i put value of g_season 'dasd' of g_id =7 in query it will give me g_id=10 row but I need g_id=12 which is displaying in this result   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db5467/69 and it is nothing but the next record

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Games WHERE g_season = 'dasd' ORDER BY g_season ASC LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should be your query if you want `g_id = 12`

```
SELECT * FROM Games WHERE g_season = 'dasd' ORDER BY g_season ASC LIMIT 1
```

if you have more than one row with identical `g_season` then you really need a second sort column otherwise you could be uncertain of the returned row if there are multiple matches.

**EDIT maybe this is what you want**

as long as you know how you want to order the matched records then you can get what you want, for example this will get you the first record (assuming we are ordering the matched records by `g_id` ASC):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Games
 WHERE g_season = 'dasd' 
 ORDER BY g_id ASC
 LIMIT 0,1
```

this will get you the second record:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Games
 WHERE g_season = 'dasd' 
 ORDER BY g_id ASC
 LIMIT 1,2
```

and you can keep incramenting like this for each record

Comment: its kind of pagination which is arranged/ordered by g_season I have to capture the current and get the next

Comment: @John why are placing > symbol? and what you want?

Comment: this is to fetch the next record from table order by g_season

Comment: @John its hard to understand your desired outcome, what do you mean by "kind of" pagination? pagination is usually achieved though some sort of numerical column not varchar.

Comment: next record order by what though? date?

Comment: @John g_season > 'dasd'  it is giving correct output. why because after dasd its fdsfsd, there are two dasd's are available and you are mentioned >dasd. View this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db5467/78

Comment: this is what i am doing I have jqgrid which several columns and when i click on any column (containing varchar data) it gets arranged by asc/desc .Then suppose user click on 1st row then detail page will open which will contain previous/next button which go from current page to next ordered by clicked jqgrid column

Comment: @Naveen Kumar this is ok but I am doing pagination so how can I miss g_id=7 and get g_id=12

Comment: @John how can you order ASC/DESC when the `g_season` value is the same? it must use some other column to order then once you have matched multiple rows, how do you plan on ordering them? once you know this it shouldn't be too difficult to move backwards and forwards through the records.

Comment: @John see my new example

Comment: Just what i though ..... thanks for ur reply

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't be like

```
 g_season = 'cvxv'
```

try run subquery as

```
SELECT * FROM Games WHERE g_season = 'dasd' ORDER BY g_season ASC
```

it gives 12 and 7 id, but when there is `>` id in 8,10,1,2

and in this case it returns `id=12` - FIDDLE http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db5467/72;

EDIT: 
only one thing came to my mind:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db5467/114

in that case there You can go further by ID

Comment: its kind of pagination which is arranged/ordered by g_season

Comment: what is Your deired result for this kind of pagination ?

Comment: this is what i am doing I have jqgrid which several columns and when i click on any column (containing varchar data) it gets arranged by asc/desc .Then suppose user click on 1st row then detail page will open which will contain previous/next button which go from current page to next ordered by clicked jqgrid column